# Execute symlink on different physical drives

Tags: symlink, executable

I have a folder on my HDD `/media/kalenpw/HDD/Documents/ShellScripts` that is full of various scripts I would like to have accessible from any directory. My previous strategy was copying all of the files into `/usr/local/bin` this worked, but was tedious when updating scripts having to change in two places.

Luckily, I recently learned about symlinks and they are the perfect fit.

I made a test script in my home folder

`test.sh`

```
print "Hello"
```

then I did `ln ~/test.sh /usr/local/bin` and like expected I could execute `test.sh` from anywhere.

The issue I'm having is I would prefer to keep all my documents on my HDD(at the directory given earlier). However, you can't link between drives so as expected I got an error

> Invalid cross-device link

so I tried doing a symbolic link like so: `sudo ln -s ./test.sh /usr/local/bin/` which created a link like expected. However, I can not execute `test.sh` from any directory(or even at all) like I would like. To ensure the file didn't lose permissions in the linking from `/usr/local/bin` I did `sudo chmod +x ./test.sh` and got an error:

> chmod: cannot access './test.sh': Too many levels of symbolic links

I can't imagine there isn't a way to do this as it seems like a common usage, but I couldn't figure out how.

Summary: how can I create a link from one file to another on a different physical drive and still retain the ability to execute the linked file.

Comment: There is one fault in your symbolic link: When you say `ln -s ./test.sh ...` it does exactly that. If you do `ls -l /usr/local/bin/test.sh`, you will see the result: `test.sh -> ./test.sh`, so it points to itself - giving an endless loop when referencing. When crossing borders, you always should use full path: `sudo ln -s /full-path-to-dir/test.sh /usr/local/bin` will then work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The proper way to access lots of scripts is to just add the directory the scripts are in to your `$PATH`. For example, I have my personal scripts in `~/bin`, so in my `.profile`, I have a line

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

That puts my `~/bin` *in front* of the existings paths, so I'm able to "overwrite" other programs by having scripts with the same name. If you don't want that, put new directories *after* `$PATH`.

So just add the directory you keep your scripts in to your path, and your problem is solved - completely without symlinks.

2) Background: On a particular filesystem, files are indentified using their *inode number*. A directory just maps file names to inode numbers. If you use `ln` without `-s` (hardlinks), you are making a new directory entry with the inode of an existing file. So, obviously, this can only work for files on the same filesystem.

OTOH, if you use `ln -s`, you are making a symbolic link (symlink): A special file that has as contents the path you specify, and this path is used instead of the file when you try to access it. You don't need to be root to make symlinks.

3) When you do `ln ~/test.sh /usr/local/bin`, then the `ln` commands detects that `/usr/local/bin` is a directory, so it assumes your really want to execute `ln ~/test.sh /usr/local/bin/test.sh`. The same happens with `-s`. It's important to keep this in mind, because you can also make symlinks to directories. But only root can make hardlinks to directories, because you could create a circular directory structure this way (and root should know enough to not do that).

4) While a hardlink does have file mode bits, a symlink doesn't: Any attempt to `chmod` a symlink will just change the file mode bits on the file that it points to.

5) I don't know what happened when you couldn't execute `test.sh`, the `Too many levels of symbolic links` error message indicates you have other symbolic links somewhere, so something got messed up. I'd need to see your directory structure to find out what happened.

6) If you really want to symlink every single script in your script directory to `/usr/local/bin/` instead of just setting the `PATH` (I don't recommend that), consider using `stow` instead: This program sets many symlinks at once. `man stow` for details.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I ended up adding it to $PATH and all works thanks for the answer